# Use menu class in walker function

Tags: menus, walker

Is there anyway, using the custom menu css classes that are turned on in the option, to apply those via a walker function to the `span` instead of the `li's`?

My custom walker:

```
class ik_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $GLOBALS['ik_walker_counter'] = 0;
        $output .= '<nav class="site-navigation" role="navigation">'.
            '<ul>';
    }

    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $output .= '</ul>'.
            '<button id="menu" class="menu-button" type="button" role="button" aria-label="Menu Toggle">'.
            '<span class="icon-menu"></span>'.
            '</button>'.
            '</div>';
    }

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;
        $GLOBALS['ik_walker_counter']++;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
        $class_names = $value = '';
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';
        $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';
        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )  ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'  . esc_attr( $item->xfn      ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ' class="c'.$GLOBALS['ik_walker_counter'].'"';
        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        if(strlen($item->description)>2){ $item_output .= '<br /><span class="sub">' . $item->description . '</span>'; }
        $item_output .= '<span class="'. $item->classes .'"></span>';
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

I was trying this:

```
$item_output .= '<span class="'. $item->classes .'"></span>';
```

But i just get:

```
<span class="Array"></span>
```

This would enable me to control the class via the menu css option so that each can have a unique class.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the need to add the same classes to the span. Can't you just style each span as `li.menu-class1 span`, `li.menu-class2 span`, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Joining all class names:

Please try:

```
$item_output .= sprintf( '<span class="%s"></span>', join( ' ', $item->classes ) );
```

instead of

```
$item_output .= '<span class="'. $item->classes .'"></span>';
```

to join the array elements of `$item->classes` into a string.

If you add for example `aaa bbb ccc` to an item's class text field, it will show up like this:

```
 Array
                (
                    [0] => aaa
                    [1] => bbb
                    [2] => ccc
                    [3] => menu-item
                    [4] => menu-item-type-post_type
                    [5] => menu-item-object-post
                )
```

### Filter out class names:

If you want to eliminate all class names containing `item` you can use:

```
$item_output .= sprintf( '<span class="%s"></span>', 
                          join( ' ', array_filter( $item->classes, 'custom_filter' ) ) 
                );
```

where the array filter callback is

```
/**
 * Only keep items not containing the string 'item'
 *
 * @param string $var
 * @return string $var | '' Empty if contains 'item'
 */

function custom_filter( $var )
{
    return ( FALSE === strpos( $var, 'item' ) ) ? $var : ''; 
}
```

*ps:* I think we are save with eliminating class names containg `item`, else you can modify it to your needs

Comment: This works thanks, however it does include not just the custom one i set in the admin, but also things like: `menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home` - is there a way to just include only the custom class i set?